# Macro to duplicate text then hide the duplicated text on MS Word keeping the formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to duplicate the text from a word document (everything including headers, footers, tables and textboxes), then I would like to hide the original text (or the hidden one) while keeping the formatting with a macro.

I've do some research and tried to make something, here what I've done until now :

```
Dim text As Word.Range
Set text = Selection.Range.Duplicate
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter
Selection.InsertAfter Text:=text.Text
text.Font.Hidden = True
```

The problem with this macro is that doesn't copy the format of the text, its make a copy of the text as a "plain text".

You have an idea of how to keep the formatting?

Comment: Do you mean headers or headings?

Comment: I think headers is the correct translations (en-tête in french)

Comment: Headers and footers are part of the page layout, which cannot be copied easily. Are you copying to the same document?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes, on the same document with the duplicated content next to each other or after the last section/part of the document. To copy this part I think that [StoryRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.storyranges) could help, I'm trying to include it on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should do what you need. You need to ensure that the `source` range does not include the start of the `target` range.

```
Dim source As Range, target As Range
With ActiveDocument
    .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    Set source = .Content
    source.MoveEnd wdParagraph, -1
    .Characters.Last.FormattedText = source.FormattedText
    source.Font.Hidden = True
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that I always mark a question as resolved.

Comment: @Satanas - please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130340/copy-all-text-from-word-document-to-antoher-word-document-without-formating and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955505/hide-non-highlighted-text-on-a-microsoft-word-document-including-text-boxes

Comment: This should pick up selected text boxes and tables but may not completely hide the space they take nor their borders/shading. (I have not tried, though.)